# Can Eurail pass be used for CityNightLine overnight trains?

Tags: trains, transportation, eurail

In [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/overnight-train-london-to-berlin/20520#20520), Mark Mayo's answer (see "Option 1") includes a CityNightLine overnight train. Can any portion of that trip be covered by a Eurail pass?

For reference, the whole trip is:

> Eurostar & City Night Line sleeper train: Hop on a mid-afternoon Eurostar from London to Paris and take the excellent City Night Line sleeper train from Paris to Berlin arriving next morning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question relates to a train that no longer exists. This question is of historical interest only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your whole trip is covered by the Eurail pass, but you should pay for reservations.

If you go to the website for Eurail pass, there is a [page specifically for international trains](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/train-reservations/reservation-fees#international). For the Eurostar from London to Paris, you must reserve a seat. In 2nd class, it is worth 89 euros.

On the [page for night trains](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/train-reservations/reservation-fees#night), it says that CityNightLine trains are accessible, but you must reserve a seat/berth. For example, a berth in 2nd class with a Global Eurail pass costs 27.5 euros.

Comment: Note that it's often cheaper to just buy a new Eurostar ticket, rather than paying the rail pass fee! Check the prices yourself before booking